# SharePoint Search Center: Can you have a custom search results page within it?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created a Search Center site and customized it with a new masterpage.  I left the default pages there, such as, results.aspx and peopleresults.aspx and created my own result pages.  I thought I could simply change the url to point to my new custom pages by going into Site Settings->Search Settings and pointing the "Site Collection Search Center" url in the "Enable Custom Scopes" textbox.

This worked, until I later noticed the url was not well-formed.  Here is an example:
/SearchCenter/Pages/SearchResults.aspx/Results.aspx?k=tyler

Notice how the out-of-box page (Results.aspx) gets tacked onto the url?  After thinking about it, I think SharePoint expects the page name "Results.aspx" to be the result page.  If I want a custom result page, am I required that it be named results.aspx?

Wanted to see what the general thought is on this...

Comment: This is your ultimate solution:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/redirect-search-to-search-results-aspx/35301#35301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I found when creating your own custom search result pages, is to name the same as the out-of-box template pages created for you in Search Center:  results.aspx and peopleresults.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Search settings should be /SearchCenter/Pages (without the page name).
Then, in the search box webpart settings set the result page to be SearchResults.aspx.

Comment: I'm using the SmallSearchInputBox delegate control, though, so I can't set the results page url out-of-the-box

Answer (score 0):

The search result page is basically a normal SharePoint page with a bunch of (connected) web parts.

You can certainly build your own page with only the web parts you need (or even with your own custom web parts) and point SharePoint Search to this new 'results' page

In my experience the page must not be named 'results.aspx'.